# How to divide a table into different levels based on values in R?

Tags: r

Suppose that i have following data

```
ID  Category    Price   Month
1   X            2       1
1   X            2       2
1   X            2       3
1   X            2       4
2   X            3       1
2   X            3       2
2   X            3       3
2   X            3       4
3   X            1       1
3   X            1       2
3   X            1       3
3   X            1       4
4   X            10      1
4   X            10      2
4   X            10      3
4   X            10      4
5   Y            5       1
5   Y            5       2
5   Y            5       3
5   Y            5       4
6   Y            2       1
6   Y            2       2
6   Y            2       3
6   Y            2       4
7   Y            1       1
7   Y            1       2
7   Y            1       3
7   Y            1       4
8   Y            10      1
8   Y            10      2
8   Y            10      3
8   Y            10      4
```

There are different prices for products in a particular category, some are low priced and some high priced. I want to have a new variable "`Price Level`" which shows whether the product is low priced product, medium priced product or high priced product.

Levels are defined as follows. 
It takes the prices of all the products in a particular category and divide into 4 percentiles.

- 1st Percentile  = Low
- 2nd and 3rd percentile = Medium
- 4th percentile = High

So the table will look like this

```
ID  Category    Price   Month   Price Level
1   X            4       1        Medium
1   X            4       2        Medium
1   X            4       3        Medium
1   X            4       4        Medium
2   X            3       1        Medium
2   X            3       2        Medium
2   X            3       3        Medium
2   X            3       4        Medium
3   X            1       1        Low
3   X            1       2        Low
3   X            1       3        Low
3   X            1       4        Low
4   X            10      1        High
4   X            10      2        High
4   X            10      3        High
4   X            10      4        High
5   Y            5       1        Medium
5   Y            5       2        Medium
5   Y            5       3        Medium
5   Y            5       4        Medium
6   Y            2       1        Low
6   Y            2       2        Low
6   Y            2       3        Low
6   Y            2       4        Low
7   Y            1       1        Low
7   Y            1       2        Low
7   Y            1       3        Low
7   Y            1       4        Low
8   Y            10      1        Low
8   Y            10      2        Low
8   Y            10      3        Low
8   Y            10      4        Low
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `lapply` across the data.frame `split` by `Category`, and call `cut` and `quantile` on each group. `data.frame` and `do.call(rbind,` reassemble the data back into a single data.frame:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$Category), function(x){
    data.frame(x, Price_Level =  cut(x$Price, 
                                     quantile(x$Price, probs = c(0, .25, .75, 1)), 
                                     labels = c('Low', 'Medium', 'High'), 
                                     include.lowest = TRUE))
}))

#    ID Category Price Month Price_Level
# 1   1        X     2     1      Medium
# 2   1        X     2     2      Medium
# 3   1        X     2     3      Medium
# 4   1        X     2     4      Medium
# 5   2        X     3     1      Medium
# 6   2        X     3     2      Medium
# 7   2        X     3     3      Medium
# 8   2        X     3     4      Medium
# 9   3        X     1     1         Low
# 10  3        X     1     2         Low
# 11  3        X     1     3         Low
# 12  3        X     1     4         Low
# 13  4        X    10     1        High
# 14  4        X    10     2        High
# 15  4        X    10     3        High
# 16  4        X    10     4        High
# 17  5        Y     5     1      Medium
# 18  5        Y     5     2      Medium
# 19  5        Y     5     3      Medium
# 20  5        Y     5     4      Medium
# 21  6        Y     2     1      Medium
# 22  6        Y     2     2      Medium
# 23  6        Y     2     3      Medium
# 24  6        Y     2     4      Medium
# 25  7        Y     1     1         Low
# 26  7        Y     1     2         Low
# 27  7        Y     1     3         Low
# 28  7        Y     1     4         Low
# 29  8        Y    10     1        High
# 30  8        Y    10     2        High
# 31  8        Y    10     3        High
# 32  8        Y    10     4        High
```

If you just want to return a single column, but don't want to worry about grouping messing up your order, you can use the equivalent

```
factor(ave(df$Price, df$Category, FUN = function(x){
    cut(x, 
        quantile(x, probs = c(0, .25, .75, 1)), 
        include.lowest = TRUE)
}), levels = c(1, 2, 3), labels = c('Low', 'Medium', 'High'))
```

A slightly less ugly version with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Category) %>% mutate(Price_Level = cut(Price, 
                                                       quantile(Price, c(0, .25, .75, 1)), 
                                                       labels = c('Low', 'Medium', 'High'), 
                                                       include.lowest = TRUE))
```

Comment: I tried to apply the code on original data which does not have equal number of rows in each category and month so i got the error " 'breaks' are not unique" so i tried to put quantile inside unique function and then i got the error "lengths of 'breaks' and 'labels' differ". How to fix it?

Comment: Can you edit with a subset of data that causes the issue?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Price_Level := cut(Price, 
             quantile(Price, c(0, .25, .75, 1)), 
            labels = c('Low', 'Medium', 'High'),
            include.lowest = TRUE), by = Category]
```

Comment: I tried to apply the code on original data which does not have equal number of rows in each category and month so i got the error " 'breaks' are not unique" so i tried to put quantile inside unique function and then i got the error "lengths of 'breaks' and 'labels' differ". How to fix it?

Comment: @Jaykhan In the example data, it is working.